# getting response on console without response on agent.add()

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to send email to someone. I print the success message in the console and my code work well and send the email successfully, but when I print it in the agent as a message it show not available before the response. Here is my code:

```
function sendEmail(agent){
//get email and name and message and subject

  console.log("Email befor getting: " +fetchedEmail);
  getEmail(agent.parameters.name).then(function(){
    console.log("the email is fetched: "+fetchedEmail);

    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: '*********@gmail.com',
        pass: '*******************'
      }
    });
    var mailOptions = {
      from: '*******@gmail.com',
      to: fetchedEmail, //receiver email 
      subject: agent.parameters.subject,
      text: agent.parameters.message
    };


    return createMessage(mailOptions,transporter).then(()=>{
      console.log("email sent successfully");//this message printed on console
      agent.add(`email sent successfully`);// this not printed in agent

    }).catch(()=>{
      agent.add(`fail`);
    });




  });
}// end of send email

function createMessage(mailOptions,transporter){
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  // i promise to send email
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("there is error");
          reject(error);
        } else {
          console.log("success");// printed on console
          resolve('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
      });



});


}//end of create message
//---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are doing asynchronous functions (your calls to `getEmail()` and `createMessage()`) using Promises, but you aren't returning a Promise from `sendEmail()` itself.

The Dialogflow library requires that, if you're doing async functions, you return a Promise so the Intent Handler dispatcher knows that you are doing async functions.

In your case, the easiest way to do this is to just return the Promise from the `getEmail().then()` chain. So changing the line like this should work:

```
return getEmail(agent.parameters.name).then(function(){
```